# Proof that all numbers between $0$ and $1$ lie between $1/(n+1)$ and $1/n$ for some natural number $n$

Tags: real-analysis

How would your prove that all numbers in the interval $(0,1)$ belong to the interval $\left[\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{1}{n}\right]$ for some natural number $n$?

Comment: What about $1/2$?

Comment: woops i meant inclusive of 1/(n+1). Just edited this.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow a few guidelines in your question.  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can find $n$ so that $x>\frac{1}{n}$ there must be a minimal $n$ satisfying that ([well-ordering principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle)). your number is between $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Why can you find such an $n$?  $x>\frac{1}{n}\iff n>\frac{1}{x}$ Are the natural numbers bounded from above?

Comment: Thanks. Archimedian principle plus well ordering principle does it.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I saw it too. I hope it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the statement to showing that all numbers in $(1..∞)$ are in $(n..(n+1)]$ for some natural number $n$ by noting that inversion $x ↦ 1/x$ is a monotone bijection of $(0..1)$ and $(1..∞)$.